# DateListPlot failing on Inflation Adjusted TimeSeries

Tags: plotting, bugs, units, time-series

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and solved in 10.4**

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

*First bug.* See output of `DateListPlot[%]`

*Second bug.* See output of `DateListPlot[wtiInflationAdjusted["Path"]]`

---

Ran across this (possible bug) today.

Here's historical West Texas Intermediate oil prices:

```
wti = TimeSeries[Import["https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/RWTCd.xls", "XLS"][[2, 4 ;; -2]]];
wti = TimeSeriesMap[Quantity[#, "USDollars"] &, wti]
```

It plots nicely.

```
DateListPlot[wti]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now to put the data in 2016 dollars and plot:

```
wtiInflationAdjusted = InflationAdjust[wti, {2016, 1, 1}];
DateListPlot[%]
```

And, well, it fails spectacularly for MMA 10.3 on Win7 x64 (also happens on OS X).

We can go about it another way:

```
DateListPlot[wtiInflationAdjusted["Path"]]
```

...and we actually get a plot, albeit with a $Failed error thrown in:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The only way I can get around an error is to do a ridiculous Quantity conversion:

```
take2 = TimeSeriesMap[
 Quantity[QuantityMagnitude[#], "USDollars"] &, InflationAdjust[wti, {2016, 1, 1}]];
DateListPlot[{wti, take2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any ideas? User error or bug?

Comment: I'll give this until tomorrow before I slap the "bug" tag on it.

Comment: I went ahead and reported to Wolfram and applied the `bugs` tag since this post got a sarcastically-huge amount of interest!

Comment: same on V.10.3 + Win 10, but no problem on 10.0 + Win 10 (same machine). Definitely, it is a bug.

Comment: I added the bug header and specified two bugs. The main bug (evaluation of `DateListPlot[%]`) is solved as of 10.4; the second (error message of `First`) persists through 11.0.1 or later. In case the latter should not be considered as a bug, please remove the corresponding parts in the header.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram confirmed bug. Assigned to [CASE:3521328].

Comment: @bbgodfrey So the answer (as a CW, by the way) a) confirms that is a bug and b) refers to the case number that Wolfram is using. Disagree with your assessment.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I am fairly certain this has been discussed by the community before, because I remember personally being on the side of allowing an *authoritative* "it is a bug" as an answer.  If you disagree with this position I encourage you to post on [meta], though please first search to see if a discussion already exists there.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  I am happy to accept your advice and shall delete my comment.  Thanks.